# ImageMagick.NET library multipage TIFF to PDF

Tags: pdf, tiff, imagemagick-convert, imagemagick.net

I'm having an issue where rather small tiff files (< 300 KB) gets blown up to like 74 MB when converted into a PDF.

```
using (var img_collection = new MagickImageCollection())
{
      using (var tif_collection = new MagickImageCollection(Convert.FromBase64String(base64_string_of_tif_image), MagickFormat.Tif))
      {
            foreach (MagickImage tif in tif_collection)
            {
                  img_collection.Add(new MagickImage(tif.ToByteArray())
                  {
                       Format = MagickFormat.Pdf                                    
                  });
             }    
             tif_collection.Dispose();
       }

       img_collection.Write("output.pdf", MagickFormat.Pdf);
       img_collection.Dispose();
 }
```

Any ideas as to how I can prevent that from happening?
The tif files are actually just scans of text.

Comment: Can you post a link to input TIFF image and output PDF file so we can take a look at them?

Comment: I can't do that. They are company invoices, so I'm not allowed to do that.

Comment: See if you can find a non-confidential TIFF image that exhibits the same behavior. Check the image with IrfanView to make sure it has the same bits per pixel/compression/etc like your problematic TIFFs

Comment: They are all invoices, so that isn't really possible for me to do. So what if I wanted to compress or whatever the PDF, if I could sense that it was above a certain size (bytes) prior to actually writing it or after, which ever is possible? - what would be the best way to do that?

Comment: Nobody knows a way/ways to somehow compress (decrease in size) resulting PDFs with this library without me providing a TIFF (which I can't) ?

Comment: @Aidal I know a couple ways of doing this, working on a solution - will post it once I'm happy with it myself

Comment: I think I actually might have found a solution or alternative myself, but I don't remember at this time what I did. Currently I'm on vacation but I'll will check when I'm back.

Comment: Awesome - I'll post mine anyway in the next few days, otherwise enjoy your vacation!

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to resolve the issues with the library I was using *ImageMagick.NET*, so the solution I found was to switch to another library which I had previous been using for other tasks, *PDFSharp* (*pdfsharp-migradoc-gdi* to be exact).

The new code to perform the same task with PDFSharp, goes like this:

```cs
using (MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedString)))
{
    strm.Position = 0;

    using (Image MyImage = Image.FromStream(strm))
    {
        using (PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument doc = new PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument())
        {
            for (int PageIndex = 0; PageIndex < MyImage.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page); PageIndex++)
            {
                MyImage.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, PageIndex);

                PdfSharp.Drawing.XImage img = PdfSharp.Drawing.XImage.FromGdiPlusImage(MyImage);

                var page = new PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfPage();

                if (img.PixelWidth > img.PixelHeight)
                {
                    page.Orientation = PdfSharp.PageOrientation.Landscape;
                }
                else
                {
                    page.Orientation = PdfSharp.PageOrientation.Portrait;
                }
                doc.Pages.Add(page);

                PdfSharp.Drawing.XGraphics xgr = PdfSharp.Drawing.XGraphics.FromPdfPage(doc.Pages[PageIndex]);

                xgr.DrawImage(img, 0, 0);
            }

            doc.Save(outputFilePath);
            doc.Close();
        }
    }

    strm.Close();
}
```

I hope this can help someone else experiencing the same issues with large PDF files when converting from TIF.